# Extract string parts separated by pound sign using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have the the following string [5111110233857£254736283045£1000£25£212541£20120605152412
£KEN£NAI],[5111110233858£254736283045£2500£25£257812£2012
0605152613£KEN£NAI]. The comma separated strings are derived from a web service and the number depends on the records returned.
Now, the fields are separated by pound sign (£). I want to extract each field and save to database.
I have tried string.split() but i don't know how to use it on unknown number of strings.

Comment: It seems, that you have to use `string.Split` *twice*: split on `,` and then each line by `£`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is `Split` by the comma, remove the `[` and `]` in each record then `Split` by the pound sign, example:

```
string test = "[5111110233857£254736283045£1000£25£212541£20120605152412 £KEN£NAI],[5111110233858£254736283045£2500£25£257812£20120605152613£KEN£NAI]";

string[] commaSeperatedStrings = test.Split(',').Select(s => s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)).ToArray();
foreach (string commaSeperatedString in commaSeperatedStrings)
{
    string[] numbers = commaSeperatedString.Split('£');
    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        // You can int.Parse each number and work with them now
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this handle any number of comma separated strings? The comma separated strings could be any number between 1 and n.

Comment: Yes, a Split doesn't need the number of entries.

Comment: I am now able to extract records using e.g var x = numbers[0];
                    var y = numbers[1]; but when i try to insert into database, each record gets inserted twice. Why?

Comment: I will have to see your code. If you're using indexs to access numbers, ditch the second foreach.

Answer (score 0):

A little program that will remove the brackets, split on comma, then split on pound sign, using `foreach` loops instead of using lambda statements (easier to understand for some).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "[5111110233857£254736283045£1000£25£212541£20120605152412 £KEN£NAI],[5111110233858£254736283045£2500£25£257812£2012 0605152613£KEN£NAI]";
        s = s.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        var split_s = s.Split(',');
        List<string> ans = new List<string>();
        foreach(var x in split_s)
        {
            var t = x.Split('£');
            foreach(var y in t)
            {
                ans.Add(y);
            }
        }
        foreach(var x in ans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Using a `List', this is a dynamic array which you can add elements as you go, regardless of the number of values in your original string.

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle the OP's problem, which is the comma seperated records.

Comment: Fair enough, I added that part of the solution.